# Using a TimeSpan as a Timer Interval

Tags: c#, timer, timespan

How can I use the value of a `TimeSpan` as the interval for a `Timer`?

Answer (score 7):

Get the [total milliseconds from the `TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalmilliseconds.aspx) to use in [the constructor for `Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0wdddfy.aspx):

```
var timer = new Timer(someTimeSpanObject.TotalMilliseconds);
```

Answer (score 1):

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalmilliseconds.aspx

```
TimeSpan interval = new TimeSpan(1, 15, 42, 45, 750); 
Console.WriteLine("Value of TimeSpan: {0}", interval);
Console.WriteLine("{0:N5} seconds, as follows:", interval.TotalMilliSeconds);
```

You can set .TotalMilliSeconds to your Interval property.