# Can't figure out how to do a timer using C#

Tags: c#

Quick question. I'm doing a project that when I open the the form it starts a timer.

When the timer is 1:00 after 1 minute it goes to 0:59 like it's supposed to happen.

But when I put the timer to 2:00 after 1 minute it goes to 1:59. I put the timer interval faster just to see what it would look like. And when it reachs 1:00 instead of becoming 0:59 becomes 1:59. I know that my code is wrong but I can't correct it.

```
public partial class Form9 : Form
{
    private int quick = 1800;

    public Form9()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form9_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        timer1.Interval = 60000;
        timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        quick--;
        label1.Text = quick / 900 + ":" + ((quick % 60) >= 10 ? (quick % 60).ToString() : "0" + (quick % 60));
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use `TimeSpan` instead of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: So how would i do it then? I'm not that good at coding so..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a TimeSpan as a Timer Interval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17123265/using-a-timespan-as-a-timer-interval)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use built-in type `TimeSpan` instead.

```
private TimeSpan quick = TimeSpan.FromHours(2); // 2 hours

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    quick -= TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1); // subtract 1 minute

    label1.Text = string.Format("{0:h\\:mm}", quick);
}
```

[How to format Timespan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings)